# AspectJ maven plugin not weaving

Tags: java, maven, aspectj

I have 2 project, 1 project is an AspectJ project that contains all my Aspects. Second one is my java project. When I try to import my Aspects to my Java project it seems that my Aspects are not working.

Here is my AspectJ pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TestAspect</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestAspect</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

My Java project pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TestJavaProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestJavaProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>TestAspect</groupId>
        <artifactId>TestAspect</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>TestAspect</groupId>
                            <artifactId>TestAspect</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                       <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>test.com.miko.Main</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                   <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>test.com.miko.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        aspectj-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.8,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

</project>
```

Can you guys help me find why is not weaving?

Comment: Don't you have to "mvn install" on the Jaspect project to make the dependencies available to the other project?

Comment: Are you building your project from Eclipse? If yes then right now you're ignoring `aspectj-maven-plugin` goals.

Comment: I tried running with `mvn clean install` in the terminal. It's still not weaving